# Using both Telerik UI Controls and WPF Controls With Same Look&Feel

Tags: wpf, telerik, wpf-controls

I would like to use both Telerik WPF UI Controls and WPF own controls in the same project. I think WPF is quite good and I need only a few controls and themes from Telerik. However, when I mix them, not all WPF controls benefit from the themes of Telerik. I read that, Telerik only support a few of WPF controls like TextBox and etc. However, I could not find a way to achieve a WPF Window with a looking like RadWindow. I have been searching and found some answers about this topic, but I think they are a little bit disorganized.

In brief, I would like to use styles from Telerik for also other WPF Controls (non-Telerik ones), but I am not sure whether it is possible or not? When I use WPF Window and RADProgressBar together, of course it does not look very good. If mixing is not a good idea I am considering completely switching to WPF. I do not have much experience with Telerik and I do not want to struggle in a mess due to this mixed environment. I want to use both if it is possible to achieve a unified style for both controls (Telerik and non-Telerik).

Comment: You can use Telerik RadWindow. I believe there is only one way to make non Telerik control looks like Telerik: create appropriate style.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at MahApps Metro (http://mahapps.com/), a WPF control toolkit that has styles to give your application a metro feel, as that is what a lot of the Telerik UI kit does as far as I can tell.

Comment: Thank you joazlazer, but I am not looking for alternatives. My question is about mixing Telerik and non-Telerik controls and may be possible problems other than this styling issue (of course style issue is my primary concern here).